# Dell laptop fan sound (with audio)

Tags: fan, cooling, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 inch laptop 5000 series, and I have been hearing a buzzing noise from the fans for months now, which is especially noticeable when there is low CPU load. What might be the cause and how can I fix it?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wh50lzl3q18xvmj/2015-08-06_20-26-41.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a dust issue. If you're comfortable with it, open up your laptop and investigate the heatsink fan. Try using a compressed air can which should remove the dust bunnies clogging your heatsink.